# how to achieve session replication in jboss 7

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have made two standalone `jboss 7` instances and I am able to load balance them using `mod_jk`.

Now, I would like to implement session replication in my app.
I have searched the internet and found that adding `<distributable/>` tag to `web.xml` would enable the session replication. Unfortunately, it is not working for me.

**For instance:** If I start both my jboss instances, run my application and shutdown the instance where session is created, the second node(instance) creates a new session. 
As a result, the session data is lost and I have to log again into my application.

Could any one please explain to me the configuration that is required in `jboss 7` for session replication to work ?

Comment: can any one explain the down vote ??.. some one down voted like 5 months after this question was asked  .. :P

Comment: I can't explain it, but I can balance it (+1). And I will edit you post, to render it more appealing.